# Pimcore Extjs how to override same method in diffrent plugins

Tags: extjs, overriding, pimcore

I am using pimcore 3. I need to put custom validation for different classes objects when any previous version of there is published. I need to implement different validation's on different plugin. The issue is if I overrides the same method in more then one plugin only one override method work. This is how I overrides the method:

```
Ext.override(pimcore.object.versions, {
        publishVersion: function (index, grid) {
          //Code goes here
        }
    });
```

I am new to both extjs and pimcore, any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
I Actually dont know the Extjs Version of doing such Thing.
but im quite sure u can get around it with Monkey patching.
by overidding the function where u wrap your plugin functions to it
example plugin code:
```

```
var old=pimcore.object.versions.prototype.publishVersion;
pimcore.object.versions.prototype.publishVersion = function(index,grid) {
  do your stuff
   return old(index,grid);
}
```